# Scroll Image Down with Slide Transition in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm attempting to make a webpage using fullpage.js, and have a very large background image.  What I'd like to do is make it so that each time the user scrolls down, it also scrolls the background image down.  Essentially, if the background image on section one starts at 0,0 and the screen is 750px tall, I'd like to make section two start at 0,750 on the background image.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve manually splitting the background image into a bunch of different images and assigning image one (from 0,0) to section one and image two (from 0,750) to section two, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callbacks fullpage.js provides such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave` or even the class added to the `body` element with the form of "fp-viewing-1-2`.

Check out [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M) I created with a similar topic. Just apply the same principle.

Comment: Oh!  I see!  Perfect answer, exactly what I needed.